# Running Cron Job, file put into root directory / not were the php script is running from

Tags: php, cron, sitemap

I setup a Cron job to run a php script.

The php script runs fine except that it outputs the file(sitemap.xml) to the root directory instead of the "/public_html/mysite.com/" directory where the script is being executed in. It works fine if I run it in a browser.

Here is the command that I'm using:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/myusername/public_html/mysite.com/buildxml.php
```

Here is the file part of the php code:

```
$xmlfile = 'sitemap.xml';
file_put_contents($xmlfile, $xmlsitemap);
```

I'm trying to figure out the best way to get the file into the "/public_html/mysite.com/" directory (Not the Root Directory).

Comment: just declare the full path `'/home/myusername/public_html/mysite.com/sitemap.xml'` for the `$xmlfile` variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either specify the full path

```
$xmlfile = __DIR__ . '/sitemap.xml';
file_put_contents($xmlfile, $xmlsitemap);
```

or change working directories first

```
chdir(__DIR__);
$xmlfile = 'sitemap.xml';
file_put_contents($xmlfile, $xmlsitemap);
```

Note, `__DIR__` means the path to the folder that contains the script that is currently being executed. You might prefer to specify the whole path instead, but they appear to be one and the same.

Comment: Adding the chdir(__DIR__); before the $xmlfile line worked perfect! Thank you for the quick response!